# Sweet Alert Yii

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, sweetalert

I am trying to use sweet alert in yii in place on the confirmation option.

I have an ajax button and I would like the sweet alert to pop up, once the user has chosen confirm or cancel I can then either continue with the ajax request or stop.

```
'ajax' => array(

'url'=>CController::createUrl('items/delete'),
'type'=>'POST',
'async'=>true,
'data'=>array('Item'=>$item['Item_id']),
'dataType'=>'json',
'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data',
'cache'=>false,
'beforeSend'=>'js:function(data)
 {
    var x = sweetalertDelete();
    if(x){alert("aaaaaaa"); return true;} 
    else {alert("bbbbb"); return false;} 
 }',
'success'=>'function(data)
{
```

I am using beforesend in order to display the sweet alert box. The issue is that as soon as the the box appears, x is returned and the alerts seen later are then shown. Here is my sweet alert code:

```
function sweetalertDelete(){
         swal({
                title: "<?php echo Yii::t('app','misc.order_delete'); ?>",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            }, 
             function (isConfirm) {
                //swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");

                if (isConfirm) {
                    alert("true");
                                  return true;
                                }
                                else
                                { 
                                    alert("false");
                                    return false;
                                }
            });




    }
```

My question is how I can make it so that the value of isconfirm is returned and until the confirm/cancel button is clicked, the ajax request will not be sent.